# Get SAMLAssertion for AWS STS's assumeRoleWithSAML

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am not able to understand how to get the SAMLAssertion token for passing as one of the parameters for the STS method -> assumeRoleWithSAML.

Please help me understand that as I already went through the [DOC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/STS.html#assumeRoleWithSAML-property)
for assumeRolesWithSAML.

Code fragment that I am using,

```
var params = {
  PrincipalArn: 'arn:aws:iam::12345678910:user/userAccount',
  RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::12345678910:role/admin',
  SAMLAssertion: 'a4FameaC4Twkfjhsadkfjhsfkhsdfsdhafislahsdfaiughdiguhdfiughdfiughdagiuhdafgiusfhdaiiiilholfjpwfmwpefmo;ivnjeiuvneinveiovnA==',
};

var stsPromise = new AWS.STS({ apiVersion: '2011-06-15' }).assumeRoleWithSAML(params).promise();
```

It says,

```
'Invalid base64 SAMLResponse (Service: AWSOpenIdDiscoveryService; Status Code
: 400; Error Code: AuthSamlInvalidSamlResponseException; Request ID: b38250b8-39
dc-4188-9bdd-a69c102a5168)'
```

Please help me out with understanding what value to be passed for SAMLAssertions? Is there any other AWS service that I can call to get it?

Comment: You need a SAML-capable SSO service to generate SAML assertions. If you don't have one, you most likely have no need to call `assumeRoleWithSAML`.

Comment: Could you please tell me about SAML-capable SSO service? I am kind of very new to AWS. Do you mean to say, I have to use Okta or Auth0?

Comment: Yup. Something like that. The SAML spec itself is hundreds of pages, so I'm afraid I won't be able to summarize that for you in a few lines. Wikipedia is a good place to start.

Comment: There are plenty of other ways to authenticate to AWS, so if you don't need SAML, best to steer clear of it.

Comment: Allright. Thanks @RobbyCornelissen. II will try to implement something